How to make GitHub treat orphan branch as orphan branch (not suggest pull requests or inform it's ahead and behind)?
I have three branches in my repo:

main
upm
gh-pages

Both upm and gh-pages are orphan branches, that is, there is no shared history between any of the branches in the repo. This is as it should be.
However, at the top of the page for the upm branch, GitHub will show the info:
This branch is 6 commits ahead of, 5 commits behind main.

Whereas for the gh-pages branch it shows no such information, even though this branch too is both ahead and behind main.
To be clear, the information is irrelevant and confusing for others who visit the page, so I don't want it to be shown.
Apparently, GitHub knows to not show this info for the gh-pages branch. How can I make it also not show it for the upm branch?

Is there some kind of branch setting or way to tell GitHub how the branch is used which will make it be treated differently in the interface?
Is the reason that the gh-pages branch is deployed via GitHub actions and GitHub infers it should be treated differently in the UI for this reason?
Or is it just a hardcoded rule in GitHub to treat branches called "gh-pages" differently?

